# Are the Sponsor Eagle prizes dictated by your progress?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

Does the reward scale with anything else than the Sponsors perk? What decides the reward you will get from the eagle (and how much views/subs/bucks its gonna give you?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sponsor Eagle randomly decides what prize you get, although Bux are rare and only appear about once a day.

However, the ability to watch an AD to increase how much you get is determined by both the size of the reward compared to your Level, and how many times you've watched an AD to increase it. The biggest prizes (including Bux) do not allow viewing to increase the reward, and once you've watched a set number of ADs in a day, you can't get any more bonuses.

Answer (score 1):

The prizes scale with both level and the sponsors perk. The higher the level you are the better rewards you will receive.

You will receive at random the following:

- Bux (once a day)
- Views
- Subscribers

Sometimes, the sponsor eagle will allow you to triple your reward by watching an advertisement. There is a limited number of times you can triple your reward per day, and it is not always offered.

Answer (score 0):

No the Sponsor Eagle reward is a randomly generated Eagle that appears every 5 minutes or so. The reward is also randomized depending on your level.